# how can I refresh screen that in drawer navigation when focused react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo, navigation-drawer, refresh

I navigate by drawer to screen with Id and this Id not changed

```
export default function ScreenPage({ route, navigation }) {
    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            Alert.alert(route.params.id);
          return () => {
            Alert.alert(route.params.id);
          };
        }, [])
      );
return (<View/>)
}
```

The Id not changed all the time till I refresh the source code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution to use

```
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native"; 
export default function Details({ route, navigation }) { 
   const isFocused = useIsFocused();
   useEffect(() => {
        fetchDetails()
    }, [isFocused])
return(<View />)
}
```

then all data on the screen will be refresh every time I navigate to screen